# if $G/Z(G) \cong Q_{8}$ show that $G$ has two abelian subgroups of index $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $G/Z(G)$ is never isomorphic to $Q_8$. for any group $G$. Hint: if $G/Z(G) \cong Q_{8}$ show that $G$ has two abelian subgroups of index $2$.

The assumption that $\mid G/Z(G) \mid=8$( whether G is infinite or finite). but I do not know how can I get an contradiction. Would someone please help me out?

Comment: Exactly where are you stuck?  What have you tried?  Do you understand how to establish the hint?  Can you figure out what to do with the hint, assuming it's true?

Comment: I would spread some information that I know and tell me if that gonna be helpful to me. I know that $Q_8$ has normal subgroups of order $1,2,4,8$

Comment: I know that the order of $Q_8$ is 8 too.

Comment: By the Correspondence Theorem, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ if and only if $H/Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: Yes. we had this Th. Would you explain how may I use this one since I have not gotten the idea.

Comment: Hint: what do cyclic subgroups in $Q_8$ look like back in $G$?

Comment: Cyclic subgroup in $Q_8$ look likes this $<i>, <j>,<k>$

Comment: @SteveD would you explain it to me?

Comment: What things (properties) can you say about those subgroups?  The hint mentions the index, so maybe you should think about that....

Comment: $Q_8$ implies that there are subgroups of index $2$